# On naming Chinese dynasties

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, we have tags [ming-dynasty](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ming-dynasty) and [qing](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qing), which is inconsistent.

We could have [ming-china](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ming-china) and [qing-china](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qing-china), or, [ming-dynasty](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ming-dynasty) and [qing-dynasty](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qing-dynasty).

How should China's dynasties be named?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I support [ming-dynasty](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ming-dynasty) and [qing-dynasty](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qing-dynasty).

- In Chinese, and their corresponding English Wikipedia articles, dynasties are overwhelmingly named with two characters, corresponding to two words in English. The second character never means "China"; the second character is either "dynasty", or is part of a two-character name of the dynasty. For example,

  - [Liao Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liao_dynasty)
  - [Northern Wei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Wei)
  - [Western Zhou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
  - ... see [dynasty names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-Four_Histories) corresponding to the twenty-four histories.
- At least one of the tag's words should be in English. A single "Ming" and "Qing" is unhelpful to a person not familiar with Chinese history or language.
- Some disunified periods are contentious as to whether the regions are "Chinese". Naming it as "dynasty" bypasses the issue completely. Names such as "Liao China" or "[Jin China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_dynasty_(1115%E2%80%931234))", for example, may not make much sense.

Comment: `tag:qing` has been merged into `tag:qing-dynasty` and synonimised.